# Thread Safe queue in C++

Tags: c++, concurrency, thread-safety, pthreads, queue

Is this the correct way to make a **Thread Safe Queue** in C++ which can handle **unsigned char* arrays** of binary data?

Notice that in the data is produced from the main thread and not a created pthread, which makes me question if the pthread_mutex_t will actually work correctly on the push and pop.

**Thread Safe Queue**

```
#include <queue>
#include <pthread.h>

class ts_queue
{

private:

    std::queue<unsigned char*> _queue_;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;

public:

    ts_queue()
    {
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
        pthread_cond_init(&cond, NULL);
    }

    void push(unsigned char* data)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        _queue_.push(data);

        pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

    void pop(unsigned char** popped_data)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        while (_queue_.empty() == true)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
        }

        *popped_data = _queue_.front();
        _queue_.pop();

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
};
```

**CONSUMER TEST:**

```
void *consumer_thread(void *arguments)
{
    ts_queue *tsq = static_cast<ts_queue*>(arguments);

    while (true)
    {
        unsigned char* data = NULL;

        tsq->pop(&data);

        if (data != NULL)
        {
            // Eureka! Received from the other thread!!!
            // Delete it so memory keeps free.
            // NOTE: In the real scenario for which I need
            // this class, the data received are bitmap pixels
            // and at this point it would be processed
            delete[] data;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**PRODUCER TEST:**

```
void main()
{
    ts_queue tsq;

    // Create the consumer
    pthread_t consumer;
    pthread_create(&consumer, NULL, consumer_thread, &tsq));

    // Start producing
    while(true)
    {
        // Push data. 
        // Expected behaviour: memory should never run out, as the
        // consumer should receive the data and delete it.
        // NOTE: test_data in the real purpose scenario for which I 
        // need this class would hold bitmap pixels, so it's meant to 
        // hold binary data and not a string

        unsigned char* test_data = new unsigned char [8192];
        tsq.push(test_data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you know the consumer never gets the data?  When I try your program out, I get a segmentation fault, and GDB tells me the consumer did get a pointer, but it's an invalid one.

I believe your problem is that you have a data race on the `_queue_` member.  `push()` calls `_queue_.push(data)` (a write on `_queue_`) while holding `push_mutex` and `pop()` calls `_queue_.front()` (a read on `_queue_`) and `_queue_.pop()` (another write on `_queue_`) while holding `pop_mutex`, but `push()` and `pop()` can occur at the same time, causing both threads to be writing (and reading) `_queue_` at the same time, a classical data-race.